# Using gtk with glade and button's background doesn't change to green

Tags: c, gtk3

i am still new to gtk and learning it. I have used glade with gtk to write this.

Basically i have made a window which has a fixed and a button in that fixed and now i want to make the background of the button green color (i have used css)

1. This is my css file (named styles.css)

   ```
   .login_button {
       background-color: #00ff00;
       color: #ffffff;
   }
   ```
2. This is my glade file (named test.glade)

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!-- Generated with glade 3.38.2 -->
   <interface>
     <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.24"/>
     <object class="GtkWindow" id="login_window">
       <property name="can-focus">False</property>
       <property name="window-position">center</property>
       <child>
         <object class="GtkFixed" id="login_fixed">
           <property name="visible">True</property>
           <property name="can-focus">False</property>
           <child>
             <object class="GtkButton" id="login_button">
               <property name="label" translatable="yes">Login</property>
               <property name="width-request">100</property>
               <property name="height-request">34</property>
               <property name="visible">True</property>
               <property name="can-focus">True</property>
               <property name="receives-default">True</property>
               <signal name="clicked" handler="on_login_button_clicked" after="yes" swapped="yes"/>
             </object>
             <packing>
               <property name="x">316</property>
               <property name="y">280</property>
             </packing>
           </child>
         </object>
       </child>
     </object>
   </interface>
   ```
3. This is my code (named test.c)

   ```
   #include <gtk/gtk.h>

   // windows and fixeds
   GtkWidget *login_window;
   GtkWidget *login_fixed;

   // buttons
   GtkWidget *login_button;

   // misc
   GtkWidget *builder;

   int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    builder = gtk_builder_new_from_file ("test.glade");
    gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, NULL);

    // window, fixed, misc
    login_window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "login_window"));
    login_fixed = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "login_fixed"));

    // buttons
    login_button = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "login_button"));

    // color
    GtkCssProvider *cssProvider = gtk_css_provider_new();
    gtk_css_provider_load_from_path(cssProvider, "styles.css", NULL);
    GtkStyleContext *context = gtk_widget_get_style_context(login_button);
    gtk_style_context_add_provider(context, GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER(cssProvider), GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);


    // title, main loop
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(login_window), "testing");
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(login_window), 600, 350); // x y
    g_signal_connect(login_window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    gtk_window_set_resizable(GTK_WINDOW(login_window), FALSE);

    gtk_widget_show(login_window);

    gtk_main();

    return 0;
   }

   // event when login button is clicked
   void on_login_button_clicked (GtkButton *b) {
    ;
   }
   ```

I had used GdkRcColor at first (which should not work with this unless i am wrong about something) and it seem to give me a faint border around the button

then i used the gtk css provider but i can't see the color green

i am having no compilation errors

it could be something related to version i am using but i am not really sure about it

i have also tried clearing gtk css cache but that still didn't work

EDIT: so i think i have some idea but still no solution to the question. It seems that the css style is being override by something else cause i was able to style the label inside the button and it works but only the button doesn't work (idk what is overriding it or how to change that)